# Can I leave the reference to android.test.runner when releasing my app?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, apk

I've added the following line in my manifest during development :

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Is it OK to ship the manifest like that or should I comment/remove this line ?

Comment: Why would your production app have that element in the first place? That should be in your separate test project.

Comment: Well, I think I messed up with MoreUnit plugin in Eclipse. It created tests directly in my project. So I guess I should simply move them to the test project.

Comment: Yes. That's one of the big benefits of Android's instrumentation framework: allowing you to keep your test code totally separate from the production code, while still allowing white-box testing if you want it.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I'll move the tests (and delete the line) before going to prod. BTW do you know what I should do with this question ? (I'm new to SO). Do I have to pick/create an answer anyway ? Or can I leave it as is ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's ok if it requires that library, otherwise you might want to add:

```
android:required="false"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll completely remove it, but if I'd have to keep other optional references, I'll do what you suggest.